# on ipad once loaded youtube video freezes all other keys until played

Tags: ipad, iframe, youtube

I am using the following code to load a YouTube video.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#LOAD").click(function(){
    data = '<iframe id="placeHolder"> </iframe>';
    $('#putItHere').html (data);
    $('#putItHere').show ();
    document.getElementById ('placeHolder').src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/7R4LJQ7-_6Y';
});
});
```

Additional buttons exist as well.  The problem is that only on an iPad or iPhone, the other buttons are frozen (do not respond to touch) until the video is started.  Once it is started, the other buttons function.  This occurs only in the 'touch' environment.  Using a 'click' environment, the buttons are not frozen.  So, for example on a lap top (using a mouse), I can load a video, see that it is the wrong one, and click to load a different video.  On an iPad, I can not click (touch) to load a different video until the loaded video has started to play.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  If the buttons are above the video, the buttons work fine on the iPad.  If the buttons are below the video by any amount greater than the height of the iframe, the buttons work fine.  If controls=0 on the source, the buttons work fine regardless of the distance below.  I have chosen the last solution.

Answer (score 1):

This has been logged as a bug with youtube api, it affects iPod/iPad/iPhone family where any links directly underneath an embedded youtube video do not work for the same height as the embedded video. See the below link:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4569